# Android Button shows in graphical layout but not on device ( This is not duplicate )

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, button, layout

The button is visible in layout of android but it's not visible on device. someone said to use the layout inspector layout inspector shows only what's visible in device, if button is not visible in device how can i find the solution with layout inspector? (Button is not visible even in layout inspector)

here is the thing the button which is present at last of xml is not visible. here is xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PlayerActivity"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="7"
         >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtsn"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/song_name_playing"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/cooljazz"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/music_icon"
            />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            >
            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekbar"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"

                >

            </SeekBar>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtsstart"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/seekbar"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:text="@string/start_time"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/seekbar">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtsstop"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seekbar"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:text="@string/end_time"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/seekbar">

            </TextView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/playbtn"
                app:backgroundTint="@null"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_pause"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnnext"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playbtn"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_next"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/playbtn">

            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnprev"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/playbtn"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_prev"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/playbtn">

            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/repeatbtn"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnprev"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_repeat"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnprev"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/recentstext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="310dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="162dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/recents"
                />



        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Here is [resulted view](https://photos.app.goo.gl/i1Adgr2aibtzvXKf6).

Here is [expected view](https://photos.app.goo.gl/jYktD4SjFBRaLTMYA).

Comment: You haven't mentioned what you found in layout inspector? Or did you not check because you didn't think you'd find anything?

Comment: Button is also not visible in layout inspector

Comment: @HenryTwist is there problem in that layout? button is also not visible in inspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer to that question,the problem is that android studio created two xml files of same name i was adding button in one xml file without realizing there is another xml this is the reason that button is not visible. after adding button to 2 xml files it started showing button

that extra file the android studio created have v21 in brackets which means **those resources that will be used when the device that is running your app is on API Level 21 or higher.**